# MySQL Error: Starting MySQL.Manager of pid-file quit without updating fi[FAILED]

Tags: mysql, innodb

After updating my.cnf with innodb value mysql not starting giving this error

```
Starting MySQL.Manager of pid-file quit without updating fi[FAILED]
```

I have checked that Innodb is running, I have added following value on my.cnf also if I add any Innodb var I am getting same error. If I remove all innodb value MySQL start and working fine.

I have added

```
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8GB
```

Also tried to add this

```
default-storage_engine = InnoDB
```

My Server memory is 16GB, Centos 6.3 and MySQL 5.1.65-cll

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL init script often gives errors about "Manager of pid-file quit without updating" but it's a red herring.

Look in the MySQL log for the real information.  By default, it should be under the data directory and is called *hostname*.err.

Given the changes you list above, the first thing I'd check is whether you tried to change the innodb log file size to 256M, but you still have an existing log file with a different size.  If this mismatch in physical file size versus configured file size is detected, InnoDB will assume it can't perform crash recovery, so it will stop itself and that may cause the MySQL to fail to start.

The solution is to do a **clean** shutdown, then physically `rm ib_logfile[01]` then start up.  InnoDB will create new logfiles at the size specified in the config file.

It's very important to remove those logfiles only after you've shut down the mysqld sevice cleanly, or you *will* lose data.

PS: It's unlikely that your innodb_log_buffer_size needs to be 256M.  The default is 8M and that's plenty for most sites.  You can monitor `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb_log_waits'` and if that value increases frequently, I'd increase innodb_log_buffer_size by 8M increments until the frequency of log waits drops.

Comment: If the innodb cannot start mysql will start with it disabled. You will see in the list of engines that innodb is missing. The most common cause for such a message is a invalid my.cnf option.

Comment: @Xnoise, yes, in MySQL 5.0 and 5.1, that's true.  In 4.1 and 5.5 MySQL will not start if InnoDB fails to initialize.  Also in 5.0/5.1 if you set `innodb=force` in the config.